# Should I sponsor an organization which aims to get more women into technology?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I recently got this message from my employee:

[image: Screen clip of in-game message - text below]
<sup>"Hi Boss! A friend of mine is greatly involved in an organization which aims to get more women into technology. They are looking for a sponsor and I thought that this would be a perfect opportunity for us. Would you like to help out?"</sup>

**What are the advantages and disadvantages of sponsoring the organization or declining the offer?**
Is the amount I'm gonna be paying for sponsorship constant? (Is it always 100K like in my screenshot?) Are there factors that affect how much it takes to sponsor this organization?

Comment: Sponsoring the organisation increases the chance of being able to hire a female employee, which is one of the game's achievements.

Comment: @WilliamLawnStewart Sounds like you should put that as an answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only does it earn you some fans, but similar to other requests you will get from your employees occasionally, denying the request can affect the efficiency of your current employees.  If you choose not to sponsor, any female employees you currently have will get a temporary decrease in efficiency, similar to what you see when you add a new employee.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably sponsor this, as hiring female employees gets you an achievement (not sure which one). Basically anything like this that is morally right (or no reason for you not to do it) you should agree upon, as it may help you in the long run, and it also gives you more fans.

Comment: Know how many fans I'm gonna get if I sponsor the organization? Am I gonna lose fans if I choose to decline?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it depends on your current fan base. A news article will pop up showing how you sponsored, and then a random amount (Generally small) of fans will show up. I'm pretty sure you loose fans, however, not 100% on that as I only have one save. Just think of the consequences of these events as opposed to real life. If someone is seen rejecting women support, they will usually be scorned upon.